# Improving related question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently asked the question below. While the first one regarding Storm Troopers (+49) was well received the one for Rebels (-1) was not. The third question on Clone Troopers was asked by another user and also received well (+7). I thought that since the one side of the question coin was good, the other would be as well...

Is there something that caused the second question to be not as well received as the first? Can I improve it to make it more attractive?

[Are Stormtroopers paid or rewarded in any way for their service?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121076/are-storm-troopers-paid-or-rewarded-in-any-way-for-their-service)

[Are Rebel Soldiers paid or rewarded for their service in any way?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121220/are-rebel-soldiers-paid-or-rewarded-for-their-service-in-any-way)

[Were Clone Troopers paid or rewarded in any way for their service?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121450/were-clone-troopers-paid-or-rewarded-in-any-way-for-their-service?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things could be affecting you questions. Below are some possibile explanations:

1. **Number of views**

   This can simply be conincidence, but some of you questions have been viewed a lot more than others:

   The **Stormtrooper** one has a lot more views

   > viewed 8252 times

   while the **Rebels** on has very few views

   > viewed 64 times

   So it is *possible* that the **Rebels** one will get more upvotes if more users view it. It's hard to tell. The same thing has [happened](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109159/do-the-imperials-know-they-are-evil) to me [before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110696/do-the-sith-know-they-are-evil?lq=1). **Editing the question brings it to the top of the questions feed, giving it a chance to be seen by more users.**
2. **Comunity retaliation**

   Some users frown on copycat questions for some reason. I guess they consider it a greedy attempt at quickly increasing one's reputation - as in "Why ask 1 good question, when I could ask 40 nearly identical ones?" you know? Some users might downvote a question, even if it's good, simply because it seems like a copycat question to them. There's no real way to tell *why* a question gets a downvote without a comment from the downvoter, which is optional. Also note that I'm not saying I think this is what's happening here (there's just the 1 downvote) but it's a possibility.

   **Personally, I vote based on each question's quality, not it's originality.**

Answer (score 3):

You just got lucky and one of your questions hit the Hot Network Questions list. Why that happens is mostly a mystery, though it involves both the question being well voted as well as its answers. Providing positive examples as NKCampbell and Milo Price did is easier to do, and it's easier for other people to confirm or just feel confident about, and therefore upvote. thegreatjedi's answer feels more speculative, so it's not surprising it has less upvotes.